# jQuery/js Removing a dynamically created checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Eric Hynds jQuery MultiSelect Widget that is being populated from a javascript file. A checkbox is created with label attached under a 'Main' checkbox if a Main is checked. How can I set it up to where the dynamically created checkbox removes if that corresponding Main is unchecked? Please see my fiddle to illustrate my problem http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/76/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".multiselect").multiselect({
        header: "Choose up to 5 areas total",
        click: function (event, ui) {
             var number1=$("#dropdown1").children(":checked").length,
                number2=$("#dropdown2").children(":checked").length;

            if (ui.checked && ((number1 + number2 >=2) || $(this).children(":checked").length >= 2)) {
                return false;
            }

            var lbl = ui.value;
            if(ui.checked){
                var ctrl = '<input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked="checked" class="chk" id="'+lbl+'">';
                $("[id^=Main]:checked").each(function(){
                    $(this).nextAll('.holder:first').append('<div>'+ctrl+lbl+'</div>');    
                });
            }
            else {
                $("[id^=Main]:checked").each(function(){
                    $(this).nextAll('.holder:first').find('div input[id="'+lbl+'"]').parent().remove();
                });
            }

        },
        selectedList:5
    });
});
```

Something like this?

```
$("[id^=id]:checked",false).each(function(){
    $(this).nextAll('.holder:first').find('div input[id="'+lbl+'"]').parent().remove();
    });
```

Or

```
if(ui.checked = false){
            $(this).nextAll('.holder:first').find('div input[id="'+lbl+'"]').parent().remove(); 

          }
            else{};
```

Comment: Instead of asking 10 questions on the same projects one after another, try to ***learn the language you're using*** so that you can figure things out yourself instead of relying on others for help. It's the only way you'll ever learn and get better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about adding this?

```
$("input[name^=chkMain]").change(function(){
    if($(this).not(':checked')){
        $(this).next('label').next('.holder').html('');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/77/

is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. Anyway to easily add the opposite? So if "1" from the dropdown is check THEN checking Main1, it will also add it?

Comment: Yes of course! you can use `if(){ ... }else{ ... }` to do something when the box is checked and something else when its not checked. This is something I came up with really quickly: http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/81/ but it still needs some work

Comment: Awesome, however theres some quirky going on. If i check Main4-6 it'll add value1-3 +1. Hopefully this will stay seperate between the two sections.

Comment: @user3191137 See my answer for the added functionality

Comment: I used the `.clone()` function to make copies of the ticked checkboxes in the drop down. I didn't add any more restrictions. You can make that really long selector more specific and then manipulate the clones to get them how you want - I only remove the `ui-state-hover` class but you can do much more... have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
else {
    $("[id^=Main]:checked").each(function(){
        $(this).nextAll('.holder:first').find('#' + lbl).parent().remove();
    })
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/78/)

I also added a functionality that unchecks the children of a main if it is unchecked. Remove the code

```
$(".checkers").click(function() {        
    if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).nextAll('.holder:eq(0)').find('div input').attr("checked", this.checked);
    }
});
```

if you don't want that functionality. You could also change `.attr("checked", this.checked)` to `.parent().remove()` if you wanted to remove the check boxes instead

If you wanted to do the opposite, meaning check the boxes then the Main, you could use the following

```
var checkedOnes = $('#dropdown1').nextAll('.ui-multiselect-menu').find('ul li input:checked');
for(var i = 0; i < checkedOnes.length; i++) {
    var lbl = checkedOnes.eq(i).attr('value');
    var ctrl = '<input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked="checked" class="chk" id="'+lbl+'">';
    $("[id^=Main]:checked").each(function(){
        $(this).nextAll('.holder:first').append('<div>'+ctrl+lbl+'</div>');    
    });
}
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/80/)

Comment: I do want that actually, that was my next step. It unchecks but could it remove the checkbox and label all together when unchecked?

Comment: Sure, just change `.attr("checked", this.checked)` to `.parent().remove()`

Comment: @user3191137 I updated to suit the request in the comment on the other answer